# Java format a number into a pattern, e.g. 1234567890 -> 1234 - 56 78 90

Tags: java, double, expression

I just wonder if it is possible (and if there is an easy way) to format a double value for a specific expression. For example:

I need this Value -> `1111111111`

formatted to this -> `1111 - 11 11 11`

anyone has an Idea?

Thanks

Comment: What is the criteria you'll be using to format it? Also, any effort from your part so far?

Comment: I think the strongest and best-to-use criteria is that the number will always be **10 digits** long. so i thought (as @Adam said) of substring but that looks a bit dirty i think. I have heard of regex, but until now i was too dumb to understand how exactly it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on exact input format, but here are some strategies

Substring chopping with .substring(beginIndex, endIndex)

```
System.out.println(input.substring(0, 4) + " - " + input.substring(4, 6)
        + " " + input.substring(6, 8) + " " + input.substring(8, 10));
```

Regex using groups to capture the given parts and then re-assembling with replace.

```
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(....)(..)(..)(..)", "$1 - $2 $3 $4"));
```

Regex pedant will say this can be written using quantifiers like this

```
(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})
```

Or even with digits

```
(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})
```

Comment: it gives 111 - 1  -  11 11 11         as output

Comment: @Keval : one dot was missing, BUT THIS IS THE **GOOD LOOKING** solution, I wanted! THANK YOU Adam!

Comment: Well now I can see how it works, regex looks pretty useful and simple to me... no extra libraries or stuff like that! (y)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the criteria of formatting your input data. You can start from checking [`Splitter`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter) class from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Take a closer look at [`Splitter.fixedLength(int)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#fixedLength(int)) method. Probably, it will be able to do desired work in elegant way.

Comment: Would maybe also be a solution but I think using regex is the most beautiful way since you don't have to take care about additional libraries...